# How to make a block explorer (like blockchain.info)?

Tags: blockchain, blockchain.info

I've tried JSON-RPC, but [it's very slow](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/20397/too-slow-json-rpc). What other things can you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think for something like blockchain.info, you'd need to write software to parse the blocks directly. You'd probably want a database of all the things you want to be able to search for, for quick lookups.